# How to convert a VS2012 VSpackage to VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, porting, vspackage

I created a `Visual Studio 2012` extension by creating a `VSPackage`. There is also a `VSIX` file generated when I build my add-in.
I would like to make my extension available on `Visual Studio 2010`. How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can add

```
<SupportedProducts>
...
<VisualStudio Version="10.0">
        <Edition>Pro</Edition>      
</VisualStudio>
```

to source.extension.vsixmanifest in VS 2012 and after that your extension should install in VS 2010, but it most probably would not work due to VS 2012 dependencies.

It is much safer to develop your extension in VS 2010 and then add support for VS 2012 with

```
<SupportedProducts>
...
<VisualStudio Version="11.0">
        <Edition>Pro</Edition>      
</VisualStudio>
```